# "Invisible Ink" text effect using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, animation, google-chrome-extension

On iOS, in iMessage you can send a message using the invisible ink effect that blurs the message and un-blurs as it's touched.

[image: Invisible Ink GIF]

Currently building a Chrome extension with React that needs to use the invisible ink animation in email. I'm new to React.js and wanted to know if anyone knew the best way to do this?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to provide your code and ask something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the "best" method, but simple. You could blur it with css and un-blur it on :hover

```
p {
      -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
      filter: blur(2px);
    }
```

Comment: You don't need vendor prefixes. See https://caniuse.com/css-filters

Answer (score 1):

I created an example for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-flower-konlt

Key findings:

**JSX**

```
<span class="invisibleInk" tabIndex="-1">
  {"This is invisible text"}
</span>
```

Notice `tabIndex`, which is needed to make normal text / span element to be focusable.

**CSS**

```
.invisibleInk {
  filter: blur(10px);
  transition: filter 240ms ease-in-out;
}

.invisibleInk:focus {
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

That contains both blur filter and the transition effect from blurred text to non-blurred

Answer (score -1):

If I have to do this I probably use a state to store info about the text, like a true/false (visible or not), to trigger the "invisible effect" should use the useEffect hook to watch this state changing and apply the animation.

This link explains react hooks like useEffect and useState which I mention:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

After that you will need to use some CSS animation effect like blink or fade in/out to make the transition more smooth, there is an example here:

https://html-online.com/articles/blinking-text-css-animation/